# Disable Bootstrap glyphicon

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

this div contains a link to open popup with bootstrap glypicon

```
<div class="panel-heading" id="divHeading">
                <div class="panel-title">
                    My Header
                    <a href="#" id="lnkPopup" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bs-example-modal-lg">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase pull-right" id="spOpenWindow"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The initial page load should disable the link.

```
$(document).ready(function () {       
        $("#lnkPopup").off();
    });
```

but its not removing the click property, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#lnkPopup").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: it should disable ONLY in the initial page load, not restricting the click operation.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use CSS for that.

```css
#lnkPopup{
   pointer-events: none;
      cursor: default;
      color: gray;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="panel-heading" id="divHeading">
  <div class="panel-title">
      My Header
       <a href="#" id="lnkPopup" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bs-example-modal-lg">
           <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase pull-right" id="spOpenWindow"></span>-->
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase" id="spOpenWindow"></span>
        </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen off() before, but why not use disabled and then check for it on click? Like this:

```
<a href="#" id="lnkPopup" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bs-example-modal-lg" disabled>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase pull-right" id="spOpenWindow"></span>
</a>
```

Then in your javascript:

```
$("#lnkPopup").on("click", function(event)
{
    if ($(this).prop("disabled"))
    {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

By doing this, then you will be able to enable it again by simply doing:

```
$("#lnkPopup").prop("disabled", false);
```

And if you want to dynamically disable it again, then just do:

```
$("#lnkPopup").prop("disabled", true);
```

If you just change the click event, then you have to mess with the event each time instead of just the disabled property.

.

### Update:

Ok so I think I understand what you mean better now. Since the javascript isn't loaded yet, you wouldn't have the click events disabled yet. Why not hide it to start with by using "display: none" like this:

```
<a href="#" id="lnkPopup" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bs-example-modal-lg" style="display: none;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase pull-right" id="spOpenWindow"></span>
</a>
```

And then in javascript do:

```
$("#lnkPopup").css("display", "");
```

Let me know if that works for you.